# Make two DIVs the same height?

Tags: html, css, height

Is this possible? I need this so if one div would become bigger in height, the other one should do the same. Both divs have different parents though. This is my mark-up:

```
<div class="aProductHeader">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <h3>omschrijving</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Toddler bestek blauw
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

I would like `.aProductHeader .omschrijving` and .`aProduct .omschrijving` to keep the same height.

Comment: can you wrap the parents?

Comment: You can't do this without JavaScript (or wrapping parents).

Comment: @Pete: I think not, as the parents include many different other elements.

Comment: Well, In fact it's kinda possible. But as Pete said, He's to wrap the parents

Comment: How would wrapping the parents help if they aren't side by side. Wrapping the parents wouldn't do anything otherwise. The parents would grow independently. Or with a single parent, the parent would grow but the children would grow independently.

Comment: ah, you'll have to use javascript then, @KingOfHypocrites it doesn't say anywhere that they aren't side by side and from the code provided it looks as if they are.  If you could wrap the parents then you can [do this](http://jsfiddle.net/3CTNQ/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use javascript

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x95ej/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="yes">
    something here<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>

<div id="nope">
  <h1>text</h1>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var one = document.getElementById("yes"),
    two = document.getElementById("nope");

if (one.offsetHeight > two.offsetHeight)
{
    two.style.height = one.offsetHeight+"px";
}else{
    one.style.height = two.offsetHeight+"px";
}
```

For using `getElementsByClassName`:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/x95ej/2/)

```
var one = document.getElementsByClassName("yes"),
    two = document.getElementsByClassName("nope");

for (i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
{
  if (one[i].offsetHeight > two[i].offsetHeight)
  {
    two[i].style.height = one[i].offsetHeight+"px";
  }else{
    one[i].style.height = two[i].offsetHeight+"px";
  }
}
```

The second option will always be as long as its 'pair', so if it's higher or smaller, one of the will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Can I use `getElementByClassName` as well? And what else should I edit in the code?

Comment: Edited @2339870 and added JSFiddle

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything. I just copied it and changed the div class names. I don't understand what is wrong.

Comment: Make sure that the `<script>` tags are just before the closing `</body>` tag & the code is in there. @2339870

Comment: Damn, I used a wrong link to load the jQuery, I'm such an idiot. This works, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If they aren't side by side, this may be a challenge. If they are side by side, you can put them in a parent div. Otherwise, you would likely have to use javascript to sync them up.

Answer (score 1):

can't you just use .omschrijving only?

Like this:

```
.omschrijving{
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't respond to changes in height.

Answer (score 1):

With javascript it would be something like this code.

```
var div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
var div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
div1.style.height = div2.style.height;
```